# Fit a line segment to a set of points

Tags: python, optimization, linear-algebra

I'm trying to fit a line segment to a set of points but I have trouble finding an algorithm for it. I have a 2D line segment `L` and a set of 2D points `C`. `L` can be represented in any suitable way (I don't care), like support and definition vector, two points, a linear equation with left and right bound, ... The only important thing is that the line has a beginning and an end, so it's **not** infinite.

I want to fit `L` in `C`, so that the sum of all distances of `c` to `L` (where `c` is a point in `C`) is minimized. This is a least squares problem but I (think) cannot use polynmoial fitting, because `L` is only a segment. My mathematical knowledge in that area is a bit lacking so any hints on further reading would be appreciated aswell.

Here is an illustration of my problem:

[image: 1]

The orange line should be fitted to the blue points so that the sum of squares of distances of each point to the line is minimal. I don't mind if the solution is in a different language or not code at all, as long as I can extract an algorithm from it.

Since this is more of a mathematical question I'm not sure if it's ok for SO or should be moved to cross validated or math exchange.

Comment: Do you want to use all the points? How would you like to define the between a point and the line? Distance in x direction, in y direction, shortest path between the point and the line?

Comment: @Chelmy88 distance is defined as the shortest path between a point and the line. In some cases this will be a line perpendicular to `L` and in other cases this will be a line to one of the end points of `L`.

Comment: Do you have any condition on the length of the line? If note the line can always be extended to make the shortest distance perpendicular. Looking at the algorithm for linear regression (which will minimize the distance in the y direction), I think it could easily be adapted

Comment: @Chelmy88 the length of the line is a predetermined constant and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is relatively similar to one already posted here, but I think is slightly more efficient, elegant and understandable, which is why I posted it despite the similarity.

As was already written, the min(max(...)) formulation makes it hard to solve this problem analytically, which is why scipy.optimize fits well.

The solution is based on the mathematical formulation for distance between a point and a finite line segment outlined in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330269/the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line-segment

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint


def calc_distance_from_point_set(v_):
    #v_ is accepted as 1d array to make easier with scipy.optimize
    #Reshape into two points
    v = (v_[:2].reshape(2, 1), v_[2:].reshape(2, 1))

    #Calculate t* for s(t*) = v_0 + t*(v_1-v_0), for the line segment w.r.t each point
    t_star_matrix = np.minimum(np.maximum(np.matmul(P-v[0].T, v[1]-v[0]) / np.linalg.norm(v[1]-v[0])**2, 0), 1)
    #Calculate s(t*)
    s_t_star_matrix = v[0]+((t_star_matrix.ravel())*(v[1]-v[0]))

    #Take distance between all points and respective point on segment
    distance_from_every_point = np.linalg.norm(P.T -s_t_star_matrix, axis=0)
    return np.sum(distance_from_every_point)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Random points from bounding box

    box_1 = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 20)
    box_2 = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 20)
    P = np.stack([box_1, box_2], axis=1)
    segment_length = 3
    segment_length_constraint = NonlinearConstraint(fun=lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.array([x[0], x[1]]) - np.array([x[2] ,x[3]])), lb=[segment_length], ub=[segment_length])
    point = minimize(calc_distance_from_point_set, (0.0,-.0,1.0,1.0), options={'maxiter': 100, 'disp': True},constraints=segment_length_constraint).x
    plt.scatter(box_1, box_2)
    plt.plot([point[0], point[2]], [point[1], point[3]])
```

Example result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition in python. The distance between the points and the line is computed based on the approach proposed here: [Fit a line segment to a set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177594/fit-a-line-segment-to-a-set-of-points)

The fact that the segment has a finite length, which impose the usage of `min` and `max` function, or `if` tests to see whether we have to use perpendicular distance or distance to one of the end points, makes really difficult (impossible?) to get an analytic solution.

The proposed solution will thus use optimization algorithm to approach the best solution. It uses scipy.optimize.minimize, see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Since the segment length is fixed, we have only three degrees of freedom. In the proposed solution I use x and y coordinate of the starting segment point and segment slope as free parameters. I use `getCoordinates` function to get starting and ending point of the segment from these 3 parameters and the length.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
from scipy.spatial import distance

# Plot the points and the segment
def plotFunction(points,x1,x2):
    'Plotting function for plane and iterations'
    plt.plot(points[:,0],points[:,1],'ro')
    plt.plot([x1[0],x2[0]],[x1[1],x2[1]])
    plt.xlim(0, 1)
    plt.ylim(0, 1)
    plt.show()

# Get the sum of the distance between all the points and the segment
# The segment is defined by guess and length were:
# guess[0]=x coordinate of the starting point
# guess[1]=y coordinate of the starting point
# guess[2]=slope
# Since distance is always >0 no need to use root mean square values
def getDist(guess,points,length):
  start_pt=np.array([guess[0],guess[1]])
  slope=guess[2]
  [x1,x2]=getCoordinates(start_pt,slope,length)
  total_dist=0
  # Loop over each points to get the distance between the point and the segment
  for pt in points:
    total_dist+=minimum_distance(x1,x2,pt,length)

  return(total_dist)

# Return minimum distance between line segment x1-x2 and point pt
# Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment
def minimum_distance(x1, x2, pt,length):
  length2 = length**2  # i.e. |x1-x2|^2 - avoid a sqrt, we use length that we already know to avoid re-computation
  if length2 == 0.0:
    return distance.euclidean(p, v);
  # Consider the line extending the segment, parameterized as x1 + t (x2 - x1).
  # We find projection of point p onto the line.
  # It falls where t = [(pt-x1) . (x2-x1)] / |x2-x1|^2
  # We clamp t from [0,1] to handle points outside the segment vw.
  t = max(0, min(1, np.dot(pt - x1, x2 - x1) / length2));
  projection = x1 + t * (x2 - x1);  # Projection falls on the segment
  return distance.euclidean(pt, projection);


# Get coordinates of start and end point of the segment from start_pt,
# slope and length, obtained by solving slope=dy/dx, dx^2+dy^2=length
def getCoordinates(start_pt,slope,length):
    x1=start_pt
    dx=length/m.sqrt(slope**2+1)
    dy=slope*dx
    x2=start_pt+np.array([dx,dy])
    return [x1,x2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Generate random points
    num_points=20
    points=np.random.rand(num_points,2)

    # Starting position
    length=0.5
    start_pt=np.array([0.25,0.5])
    slope=0

    #Use scipy.optimize, minimize to find the best start_pt and slope combination
    res = minimize(getDist, x0=[start_pt[0],start_pt[1],slope], args=(points,length), method="Nelder-Mead")

    # Retreive best parameters
    start_pt=np.array([res.x[0],res.x[1]])
    slope=res.x[2]
    [x1,x2]=getCoordinates(start_pt,slope,length)

    print("\n** The best segment found is defined by:")
    print("\t** start_pt:\t",x1)
    print("\t** end_pt:\t",x2)
    print("\t** slope:\t",slope)
    print("** The total distance is:",getDist([x1[0],x2[1],slope],points,length),"\n")

    # Plot results
    plotFunction(points,x1,x2)
```